# PHP include not working for index page

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to use PHP include on my website but I am running into trouble...

To start this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Future | Origins</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
            $p = $_GET['p'];

            include('include/header.php');

            switch($p) {

                case "about":
                include('include/about.php');
                break;

                default:
                    $p = "include/main.php";
                break;

            }

            include('include/footer.php');
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It only shows content for my index page if my URL is styled like

```
localhost/index.php?p=
```

I would like it to show content for my index page using the default

```
localhost
```

I don't have much knowledge of PHP and there never seems to be a straightforward solution. I am including multiple pages in my website using a switch case.

Many thanks

Comment: So add an `else` with what to include when no parameter is given; right now you don't do anything when `p` is not passed in the query string.

Comment: Thank you, that has solved it. Also moved header and footer include outside of IF statement. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your includes outside the if statement

```
<body>
<?php
    include('include/header.php');
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        $p = $_GET['p'];



        switch($p) {

            case "about":
            include('include/about.php');
            break;

            default:
                $p = "include/main.php";
            break;

        }
    }
        include('include/footer.php');

?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. Used this as well as jeroen's answer :)